# RouteBoxer for HereMaps - adding POI around routes

Tags: android, here-api

Is there any RouteBoxer for HERE API? I can't find anything useful while reading the docs.

I want to search for routes from A to B, then search POI around the routes. How do I do this?

Targeting Android for now.

Comment: Just to clarify, which platform is the question targeting (i.e. Web, Android, iOS, ...)

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: please add the `android` tag to the question as well (in addition to the `here-api` tag)

Answer (score 1):

The `Route` object has the `getBoundingBox()` API which returns a `GeoBoundingBox`. You can use the returned `GeoBoundingBox` to set the search area for your POI search. For example `ExploreRequest#setSearchArea(GeoBoundingBox boundingArea)`

More Info:

- [Routing API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-route.html#topic-apiref__getboundingbox-void)
- [Search and Discovery User Guide](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/places.html)